# MySQL (XAMPP) with MINGW64 on Windows

Tags: mysql, xampp, mingw-w64

I use XAMPP for Windows, and I also use Git for windows.
I love the Git Bash console (I think Git comes with MINGW64)

But, when I need to access mysql functions from my XAMPP setup, I have to use the console that opens from XAMPP Control Panel, which is not as good as a linux-like console, like MINGW64.

[image]

Is there a way to run MySQL commands in Windows through this MINGW64 console?

Example of what I want to do in the linux-like console:

```
mysql my_database > file.txt <<EOF
select * (complicate statement with multiple lines)
EOF
```